# Sympy right hand side of inequality

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy to solve a simple inequality. After solving it, I want to assign the right hand side of the solution to a new variable.

```
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x', real=True)
sol = reduce_rational_inequalities([[x*0.2 >= 1]], x)
print type(sol), '\n', sol
>> <class 'sympy.core.relational.GreaterThan'> 
   x >= 5.0
```

I have tried

```
rhs = sol.rhs()
>> TypeError: 'Float' object is not callable
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses here, `.rhs` is an attribute. You can write:

```
rhs = sol.rhs
```

`sol.rhs` will return a SymPy `Float` object.

Comment: thank you! I've missed the `@property` decorator in the code.